# jQuery - Is it possible for a script to modify the markup in the DOM generated by another script?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a script(a) that generates a div with the id myCarousel (in the markup in the DOM). Is it possible for another script(b) to search for this element in the DOM and have its way with myCarousel?

If I add the myCarousel div straight into the HTML file, script(b) can access it fine and further add elements/classes/etc, but not if it's generated by the first script(a).

Comment: shouldn't be a problem if it's in the DOM - some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to access it before  `$(document).ready` then it doesn't yet exist to javascript/jquery.

If you are attempting to access it after  `$(document).ready`, and it is not working correctly, do a view source to see if the process that is generating the id is altering the id (as, for instance, asp.net and sometimes vendor controls will do).

If it doesn't work after that you might try altering your generator to add a class to the div and then using a class selector $(".aCarousel") rather than an ID selector $("#myCarousel")

*Remember that depending on what you are trying to do with the object once you select it, you may need to identify the [n] element of the selection. Even ID selectors in jquery return an ARRAY of elements that match the ID value. Of course there should only be one item by an ID, but that is how jquery operates.*

PS: if these generalities don't work, please post some code :)